# Storing single characters

Tags: c++, string, char

If I want to store a single character say 'c' am i better of using

```
std::string myChar = 'c';
```

rather than the built in char type?

```
char myChar = 'c';
```

Is there any safety gained by storing single characters as string?

Comment: At most you get some extra convenience depending on what you want to do with it. But since you don't show what this is for, it's impossible to say. *"Is there any safety gained by storing single characters as string?"* Why would it be unsafe to put a `char` into a `char` variable?

Comment: Char can be used in math operations, like 'a'+5, or 't'<65. If you try to avoid that, std::string is fine but I think it's overkill. Aldo, char is often used as a byte type, ex `char x = 30;`

Comment: _"Is there any safety gained by storing single characters as string?"_: safety in terms of what?

Comment: Things get a bit icky if you have a single character like `ü`, let alone if you need to deal with Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little safety gained as you won't accidentally use the string for calculations.

```
int a = 5+myChar;
```

Will give a compiler error if it is a string and wont if it's a char, because those are seen as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that the first example doesn't compile. It has to be

```
std::string myChar = "c";
```

(with double quotes). I see more disadvantages in this approach:

- It will consume way more memory than required. With short-string optimizations the data will not be stored on the heap, but a string is still 3 words long (often 1 word is 4Byte, so that would be 12 Bytes) compared to one byte<sup>1</sup> when using `char`.
- The access to that char is really inconvenient, you would always have to use `.front()`, `.back()` or `[0]` to access that char.
- It doesn't convey the meaning of your variables, it's like replacing all `int`-variables in your program with a `std::vector<int>` with a single element.

The only "safety" I can see, is as AlexGeorg already mentioned, you can't mistakenly use it in calculations. But that's it and this could also be seen as disadavantage.

So, no, your most likely *not* better of when using a string to store a single character. Except you have some really specific circumstances.

---

<sup>1</sup>plus maybe some padding.

Answer (score 0):

The positive thing using string is the error at compile time when you trying to use variable for a mathematical expression example :

```
int sum = 15 + myChar;
```

You have instead some negative thing to take in consideration :

- The first one is the performance, allocate a **string is more expensive** in term of memory occupation and time of execution.
- The second one is that the **String does not assure** that the variable has a single character. So you have to pay attention when you use it.